# Can you play online with friends and strangers?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart 8, you can play against random people online, or you can play in private rooms with friends. I'm hoping I'm missing something, but: Is there a way you and a Nintendo Network friend can go join a room together, then let the room fill up with other random players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well yes there is a way you and a Nintendo Network friend can go join a room together, but sadly one of you is going to need to be one of those random players who joins your room. You can select join room, and you will attempt to join your friends room as a random player.

Comment: Indeed, if you go to your friends list and they're in a race, they'll have a checkered flag icon. Click on the friend, and you can "Join" that way.

Comment: yep this is right. It functions in just the same way as MK7